# Unable to scroll horizontally in webtable(Selenium with C#)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

issue 1 : Web table with 16 columns is in page. When i am trying to scroll horizontally page is moving but not a web table. i tried with java script executor but it's not working at all.

when i tried keyboard functionality using Tab then is displaying element not intractable exception

issue 2 : Web table having more columns and these columns are not loading at a time. when scroll then that related columns are loading. How can i handle in C# selenium

Comment: Can you show what you have done til now.

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(500,0)");

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.